# Debian Administrative Password Issues

Tags: debian, sudo

I installed Debian Lenny few minutes ago and I have a big problem.

I created an user successfully. I can login with GDM. For now everything works perfectly.

But, when I try to run root terminal, run Synaptic, it prompts for a root password. When I enter it...nothing happens. Window just disappear and nothing happens.

When I try:

```
 sudo aptitude install package_name
```

when I enter my password I'm getting:

```
user is not in the sudoers file.  This incident will be reported.
```

When I try `su` after providing correct root password I'm getting "Authorization failed".

Any ideas how to solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably set your password with the wrong keymap.
You can recover by booting into "single" user mode.

When boot loader comes up:

- Choose kernel to boot (arrow keys)
- Press "e" to edit the entry.
- Use the arrows to go to kernel line.
- Press "e" to edit this entry.
- At the end of the line add the word "init=/bin/bash"
- Press "ESC" to go back to the parent menu.
- Press b to boot this kernel

Now you will enter single user mode without having to enter root's password. You
need to remount the root filesystem to read-write with:

```
# mount -o remount,rw /
```

Change password for root with:

```
# passwd root
```

Remount the filesystem to read-only again:

```
# mount -o remount,ro /
```

Now reboot and you are all set.

Comment: Now tell me please, how did you know it was wrong password? I spent over 9 hours trying to figure it out. Thanks!!!

Comment: I have done the same thing myself ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Debian doesn't automatically add users to the sudo list as Ubuntu variants do.
You will have to use visudo as root (when you recover the password) and add user to the authorised list.

Answer (score -1):

why dont reset the passwd for root

A reboot the server if your using 9.04 and above then you need to hold "shift" key while rebooting the server use down arrow key last option for single use mode $passwd root

B if your using old version of ubuntu then while rebooting press "ESC" boot in single user mode

and follow the step from following link

http://studyhat.blogspot.com/2010/05/resetting-root-password-via-grub-kernel.html

Comment: "9.04" is Ubuntu - the poster said "Debian Lenny".